# Is there a C#.NET 5.0 approach to monitoring TCP port availability for concurrent outgoing network requests?

Tags: .net, sockets, port, .net-5

We have a C#.NET 5.0 application that makes hundreds of thousands of network requests.

To improve performance, we send thousands of concurrent network requests. Sometimes this leads to port exhaustion exceptions.

We would like to prevent exceptions by monitoring port availability and sending another network request only when available ports exists.

E.g.,

```
var maxOpenPorts = GetMaxOperationSystemOpenPorts();
var openPorts = CountCurrentlyOpenPorts();
var arePortsAvailable = maxOpenPorts > openPorts;

if(!arePortsAvailable) {
  Wait();
}

SendNextNetworkRequest();
```

How can we `GetMaxOperationSystemOpenPorts` and `CountCurrentlyOpenPorts` in .NET 5.0?

P.S. We think that we can count of currently open ports like this:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation
   .IPGlobalProperties
   .GetIPGlobalProperties()
   .GetActiveTcpConnections()
   .Count;
```

We also know how to count open posts from the PowerShell like this:

```
netstat -o | Select-String ESTABLISHED | Measure-Object
```

Comment: Have you tried to increase the number of ports available in the O/S?

Comment: We have not tried to increase the number of ports available in the O/S. I assumed our concurrent requests will grow even further and exhaust the ports at the higher number. So that if we increase the number of available ports from say 5K to 10K, then exhaustion will happen at 10,001 instead of at 5,001. Please correct me if I am wrong here. In any case, I would love to be able to monitor available ports and pause application processing until ports become available.

Comment: To increase the range to the maximum allowed value for tcp v4, use the following command: `netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=1025 num=64511`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance